# uncompress a .txt.gz file in mac?

Tags: compression, gzip

How do I uncompress a `.txt.gz` file in mac?

I already tried `unzip file.txt.gz` but it says it cannot find zipfile directory in one of file.txt.gz or file.txt.gz.zip, and cannot find file.txt.gz.ZIP, period.

Answer (score 207, accepted):

`gunzip file.txt.gz` in Terminal.